# MySQL Advance Joins

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have recently been learning MySQL and wondering if some one could help me with this problem I am working on..

I have two tables,

First is a departmentTable

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Department | Employee1 | Employee2 | Employee3 | Employee4 | Employee5 | Employee6 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Finance    | Tim C     | Nora C    | Susan P   | Martin S  | Donal D   | Zita P    |
| HR         | Yvonne S  | Marcus F  | Mark B    | Peter S   | Ola G     | Gina P    |
| IT         | John W    | Matt R    | Paul M    | Tom Y     | Jean S    | Martin T  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Second is a employeeDetails Table

```
+--------------+-------+------------+--------+
| EmployeeName | Shift | Employment | Salary |
+--------------+-------+------------+--------+
| Donal D      | Night | Full       | 30000  |
| Gina P       | Night | Part       | 21000  |
| Jean S       | Night | Full       | 30000  |
| John W       | Night | Full       | 24000  |
| Marcus F     | Night | Full       | 21000  |
| Mark B       | Day   | Full       | 23000  |
| Martin S     | Day   | Full       | 23400  |
| Martin T     | Day   | Part       | 31000  |
| Matt R       | Day   | Full       | 22000  |
| Nora C       | Day   | Full       | 22000  |
| Ola G        | Night | Full       | 21400  |
| Paul M       | Day   | Part       | 23000  |
| Peter S      | Day   | Part       | 25000  |
| Susan P      | Day   | Part       | 23000  |
| Tim C        | Day   | Full       | 24000  |
| Tom Y        | Day   | Full       | 23400  |
| Yvonne S     | Day   | Full       | 24000  |
| Zita P       | Night | Part       | 31000  |
+--------------+-------+------------+--------+
```

I am trying to find a way if it is possible to have a query that will find which department has 4 day and 2 night shift employees. so it should output something like this..

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Department | Employee1 | Employee2 | Employee3 | Employee4 | Employee5 | Employee6 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Finance    | Tim C     | Nora C    | Susan P   | Martin S  | Donal D   | Zita P    |
| IT         | John W    | Matt R    | Paul M    | Tom Y     | Jean S    | Martin T  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Any help appreciated, I know it is not the best way to store data and retrieve them, but I am trying to understand and learn more about joins and counts in MySQL.

Comment: Fix your table structure. Store Employees in  one column

Comment: I am covering some training material which suggested the above data structure. so I am just trying to understand if it even possible

Comment: Please first normalize your database before write advance query . Otherwise it will waste your time and talent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your table structure by storing Employees in one column.

With that said, you could try this:

```
select
    d.*
from departmentTable d
join employeeDetails e on e.EmployeeName in (
    d.Employee1, d.Employee2, d.Employee3,
    d.Employee4, d.Employee5, d.Employee6
)
group by d.department
having sum(e.shift = 'Night') = 2
and sum(e.shift = 'Day') = 4
```

Comment: this worked like a charm.. Thanks really much for your help, the online course I am doing is focusing a lot on these advance queries before normalize the database.. but thanks very much for your help again

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use a table where you store all employees with their details and add a detail there that references to an department. Never use your approach with employee1-n.

Also as I see that Nora C is present in two departments maybe take a look at m-n relationships. Google is your friend

Comment: So looks like it is was copy and paste typo.. it should have been Marcus F.. Have been kinda of stuck, hence I decided to ask.. I will still chip away at it.. thanks